# Java Android remove name of Application

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment and an activity.  I want to display name of tags(fragments) but I don't want to show name of application in actionBar.
This is my activity: when I remove an `ActionBarActivity` I can not use a `FragmentManager`

```
public class ObjectListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener  {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_object_list2);

        // View pager for showing many fragments over a single activity
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Getting fragment manager to control fragments
        FragmentManager fragmnetManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Setting adapter over view pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmnetManager));

        // Implementing view pager pagechangelistener to navigate between tabs
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {

                // Setting navigation of tabs to actionbar
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });

        // Getting actionbar
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        // Setting navigation mode to actionbar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Now adding a new tab to action bar and setting title, icon and
        // implementing listener
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Wszytskie");
        // tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Grupy");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        // Now finally adding all tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0,
                                FragmentTransaction arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                              FragmentTransaction arg1) {

        // Setting current position of tab to view pager
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0,
                                FragmentTransaction arg1) {

    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        // Getting fragments according to selected position
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (i == 0) {
            fragment = new FragmentAllObjectActivity();
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentGroupObjectsActivity();
        }

        // and finally returning fragments
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        // Returning no. of counts of fragments
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is ambiguous ,nice commenting though.

Comment: @Caspain I want to show a name of tags but I don't want to show a name of Application

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onTabSelected` add the line:

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                              FragmentTransaction arg1) {

        // Setting current position of tab to view pager
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        setTitle(getText(tab.getPosition()));
    }
```

You have to implement a `getText()` method which return the right text based on the current fragment like:

```
public String getText(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab){
   // if tab == tabType 1 return "Title 1" 
   // else return "Title 2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code in your onCreate method

```
                 setTitle("");//it will remove your app name
```